# Apple Watch Healthkit access inconsistent

Tags: ios, authorization, apple-watch, healthkit

I have two sets of [Apple Watch Series 2 / iPhone 7] combinations and, when I run the application I've written that reads the heart rate from the HealthKit, it runs perfectly on one but I get an "Authorization request canceled" error on the other watch.  I have no idea why.

The iOS on the working iPhone/Watch is 11.2.2/4.2.2 while the iOS on the non-working set is 11.2.5/4.2.2 (so newer).

When I run it on the working set the first time, I get the authorization dialog and the settings under Privacy allows me to turn on the heart rate but, on the non-working set, the settings under Privacy is a blank screen.

The app has been verified on both iPhones so that's not the issue.

This is driving me nuts and I have no idea what is left to try.  I've restarted XCode, deleted and re-installed the app, and will reboot my machine next although I'm not sure that will do anything.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.